# Show integral of decreasing set is zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In my homework I am trying to show that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{X\backslash K_n} |u|\, d\mu = 0$$ 
and $K_n=\{|u|\leq n\}$ and $u \in \mathcal{L}^1$

My basic idea was to say that:

For $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $X\setminus K_n=\emptyset$ and therefore $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and get we get the equality.

However I am not sure how if this actually shows that the integral of some Lebesgue function is actully zero just because the measure is zero? Or if I need to take convergence into consideration

Any hint/help would be very appreciated

Comment: What are the $K_n$'s?? ..Do they decrease to the empty set? I cannot understand your question

Comment: If $u\in L^1(X,\mu)$, then $\int_{X\setminus K_n}\lvert u\rvert\,d\mu=\int_X \left\lvert u\cdot 1_{X\setminus K_n}\right\rvert\,d\mu$ and, if $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} (X\setminus K_n)=\emptyset$, then you can use dominated convergence theorem since $\left\lvert u\cdot 1_{X\setminus K_n}\right\rvert\to0$ and it is dominated by $\lvert u\rvert$.

Comment: It is apparent, on the other hand, that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{(0,1]\setminus [1/n,1]}\frac1x\,dx=\infty\ne 0$

Comment: @MariosGretsas Sorry, I missed out a description, have updated it now

Comment: Gae has given a simple counterexample to the updated version. You're leaving out a hypothesis...

Comment: Maybe $u \in L^1$

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes, you are right. I have added the Lebesgue assumption, thanks. But what I don't understand - is it not enough just to show that $\mu(X\setminus K_n \rightarrow 0)$? I don't see why DCT is needed

Comment: @Daniel i added an answer...holp this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bigcap_n X \setminus K_n=\{x:|u(x)|=+\infty\}$ and since $u$ is integrable we have that $u$ is finite a.e so $\mu(\{x:f(x)=\infty\})=0$

Also $u_n(x):=|u(x)|1_{X\setminus K_n}(x) \to |u(x)|1_{\{x:f(x)=\infty\}}(x)$

So from DCT $$\int|u(x)|1_{X\setminus K_n}(x)d\mu(x) \to \int |u(x)|1_{\{x:f(x)=\infty\}}(x)d\mu(x)$$ $$=\int_{\{x:f(x)=\infty\}}|u(x)|d\mu(x)=0$$
since $|u| \geq 0$